# Display formatted text instead of raw text in .json file

Tags: .net-core, blazor

This is my json file.

```
{
      "GroupBy": "Communications / Network Security",
      "IdentifiedRisk": "<b>Are system and <i>network environments</i> protected by a firewall or virtual firewall to ensure business and customer security requirements?</b>"
     
    },
```

I have to format as bold and italics while it displays in the browser but unfortunately it displays the raw html instead of formatting it.

required output:

**Are system and *network environments* protected by a firewall or virtual firewall to ensure business and customer security requirements?**

actual output:

```
<b>Are system and <i>network environments</i> protected by a firewall or virtual firewall to ensure business and customer security requirements?</b>
```

How will I format the text/text area?

Comment: Use `MarkupString`, `@MarkupString(IdentifiedRisk)`

Comment: It is @((MarkupString)IdentifiedRisk)

Answer (score 0):

```
@((MarkupString)IdentifiedRisk)
```